# How to display associations from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

Associations are my rails achilles heel.

I have 3 models and controllers: `User`, `List`, `Item`.

User can can create `username` and `password`. List can create list `name`, Item can create `item_name`

Ideally, a list belongs to a user. An item belongs to a list. List has many items. User has many lists. So I came up with:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  delegate :user, to: :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items, through: :lists
end
```

On rails console, just to make sure, I checked the columns:

```
2.2.1 :005 > List.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at"] 
2.2.1 :006 > Item.column_names
 => ["id", "item_name", "list_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]     
2.2.1 :007 > User.column_names
 => ["id", "username", "password", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

So I went to create new User, Item, and List:

```
User.create(username: "iggy2", password: "helloworld") 
#let's say iggy2 has user_id 2.
```

I want to have iggy2 to have a List named "important stuff", with Item "Wash dishes".

```
List.create(name: "Important", user_id: 2 ) #let's say this has id of 1

Item.create(item_name: "Wash dishes", list_id: 1)
```

I assumed that Item is connected to List and List is connected to User. But when I type User.last.name, instead of seeing "Important", I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name'`. I also get similar error on List.last.item_name

This is what my schema looks like

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "item_name"
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

What is missing on my code? Was my assumption wrong? How can I get `User.last.name` or even `User.last.item_name` to show the last user's item name or list name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but your assumption is wrong. `User.last` returns an user record so you will get `NoMethodError` when accessing methods in associated records.

I suppose what you want is below:

```
List.where(user_id: User.last.id).pluck(:name) # Return all list names belong to last user

id = List.find_by(user_id: User.last)
Item.where(list_id: id).pluck(:item_name) # Return all item names belong to last user
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I just thought of a follow-up question. Since I am still learning polymorphism, I wasn't sure if it is possible, but is it possible to have the command User.last.item_name or User.last.name (name = list name) and return a value? (meaning, is it possible, to go from User to another associated item's attribute directly?), or does it have to go through process mentioned by your answer above? Thank you so much!

Comment: surely you can apply polymorphic association here ie `Item` can belong to both `User` and `List`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations should give should give good example